# Unmarshaling JSON with nested map[string]interface

Tags: json, go, interface

I have a json which is like a nested map[string]interface{} and I cant seem to parse it, it looks like

```
{
  "data": {
    "xtoy": {
      "1": 2,
      "2": 3,
      "3": 4
    },
    "atob": {
      "1": 4,
      "2": 5,
      "3": 6
    },
    "mton": {
      "1": 9,
      "2": 8,
      "3": 7
    },
    "itemdetails": {
      "1": {
        "item": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "item1"
        },
        "details": {
          "details": {
            "1": {
              "product": {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "premium"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 
  "Date": "2011-07-01"
}
```

is there any ways to simple deal with this? I'm kind of  at my whits end.
**EDIT**
I've tried making a struct like

```
type Data struct{
    xtoy map[string]interface{} `mapstructure:"xtoy " json:"xtoy "`
    atob map[string]interface{} `mapstructure:"atob" json:"atob"`
    mton map[string]interface{} `mapstructure:"mton" json:"mton"`
    itemdetails[]CustomStruct `mapstructure:"itemdetails" json:"itemdetails"`
}
```

Now the first 3 work but when I get to itemdetails, I need to access fields inside the interface but to add to the problem itemdetails is an array of interfaces. CustomStruct is a nested struct that follows structure of json

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? Post your code.

Comment: @icza I've added some more code, does this help?

Comment: If you add your code, show your actual JSON input your code is supposed to process. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: @icza i added some actual code but the custom struct code is too big, is this enough?

Comment: You have to export struct fieds (start them with capital letter). Also, `"itemdetails"` in JSON is a JSON object, you have to use a struct for it. `Data.itemdetails` in Go is a slice. Slice may be used to unmarshal JSON arrays, not objects.

Comment: @icza thank you, so much i'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

To approach this kind of nested json objects, ideally you should break them down to individual objects instead of interface as they are more safe

Create their own struct for simplicity like below:

```
type Xtoy struct {
    Num1 int `json:"1"`
    Num2 int `json:"2"`
    Num3 int `json:"3"`
}
type Atob struct {
    Num1 int `json:"1"`
    Num2 int `json:"2"`
    Num3 int `json:"3"`
}
type Mton struct {
    Num1 int `json:"1"`
    Num2 int `json:"2"`
    Num3 int `json:"3"`
}
type Item struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
type Product struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
type Num1 struct {
    Product Product `json:"product"`
}
type Details struct {
    Num1 Num1 `json:"1"`
}
type Details struct {
    Details Details `json:"details"`
}
type Num1 struct {
    Item    Item    `json:"item"`
    Details Details `json:"details"`
}
type Itemdetails struct {
    Num1 Num1 `json:"1"`
}
type Data struct {
    Xtoy        Xtoy        `json:"xtoy"`
    Atob        Atob        `json:"atob"`
    Mton        Mton        `json:"mton"`
    Itemdetails Itemdetails `json:"itemdetails"`
}



type Finale struct {
        Data Data   `json:"data"`
        Date string `json:"Date"`
 }
```

Comment: The problem is number of fields changes, xtoy may has 3 fields to 300 fields